# Explicitly specifying the return type of a class method?

Tags: haskell, types, monads

Consider the below:

```
class Test m a where
   t :: Int -> m a

instance Test [] Int where
   t i = [i]

instance Test Maybe Int where
   t i | i == 0   = Nothing
       | otherwise = Just i

main = do 
  print $ t (22 :: Int) --Error!
```

This will throw with the following error:

```
Ambiguous type variables ‘m0’, ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘print’
  prevents the constraint ‘(Show (m0 a0))’ from being solved.
```

This is due to the fact the compiler has no way of identifying what instance of `m a` to use. How can I explicitly state this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Annotate the full call to `t`:

```
print (t 22 :: Maybe Int)
```

or annotate `t` itself

```
print $ (t :: Int -> Maybe Int) 22
```

As a more advanced alternative, with the proper extensions on, one can pass the type level arguments explicitly

```
print $ t @Maybe @Int 22
```

depending on the class at hand, this may save you to type a very long annotation.